# Dijkstra Partitioning Algorithm : Special Case

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, sorting, partitions

I have been exploring Dikstra partitioning Algorithm. Below are my given:

```
R = Red
W = White 
B = Blue
```

I have this unpartitioned array.

```
| W | B  | R |  W  | R  | W | B |  W  |  W |
```

I want it partition in the format: R, W, B consecutively.

```
| R  |  ?  | W  |  B |
0     i     j    k    n
```

Given:

```
 i = 0
 j = n
 k = n
 n = number of elements
```

Below is my algorithm:

```
 while  (i < j)
 {
     case a[i]:
         R : i++;
         W : j--; swap(a[i], a[j]);
         B : j--; k--; swap(a[i], a[k]); swap(a[i], a[j]);
     end case 
 }
 //Done Sorting
```

The output should be like this:

```
 |  R  | R  | W  |  W  |  W  |   W  |  W  |  B  |  B |
```

My question is:

1. Can I reduce the number of swaps? If yes, how?
2. Is the algorithm applicable if there are 4 colors to be partitioned?

Thank you. I really need to understand this concept.

Comment: Have a look at [gapped insertion sort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_sort) for an idea.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No. Note that the worst case of this algorithm is when all elements are blue. In such case, you will need $2\cdot n$ swaps in the worst case. When all elements are blue the number of swaps can be zero.

Optimal algorithm:

I think that the following algorithm is the optimal one:

1. Count the number of Reds, Blues and Whites in the array.
2. Denote $n_{color}$ the number of elements of $color\in \{ Blue,Red,White \}$ in the array.
3. Define $i=0, j=n_{Red}-1$, and $k=n_{Blue}+n_{Red}-1$,  i.e., counters over the Reds,Blues and Whites arrays in the corresponding  , respectively.
4. Increase i,j,k until either the counter is lager than the size of the corresponding array (i.e., $i=n_{Red},j=n_{Blue}+n_{Red}$ and $k=n$), or that the corresponding element is not in the appropriate color (i.e., $a[i]$ is not red, $a[j]$ is not blue, $a[k]$ is not white). The algorithm stops iff when all counters are lager than the size of the corresponding array $i=n_{Red},j=n_{Blue}+n_{Red}$ and $k=n$.

Now, if $a[i]$ is blue and $a[j]$ is red, then we can swap between them, and increase the counters of $i$ and $j$ until possible.  The same can be said if $a[i]$ is white and $a[k]$ is red or  $a[j]$ is white and $a[k]$ is blue. Thus if there are two elements of  $(a[i],a[j],a[k])$  with the same color- we can swap the corresponding pair, and  increase the corresponding counters.

In the edge case where $a[i]$ is blue and $a[j]$ is white, and $a[k]$ is red, we must do $2$ swaps. The same happens if $a[i]$ is white and $a[j]$ is red, and $a[k]$ is blue.

The number of swaps in such algorithm is at most $\frac{2}{3}n$, in case the array begins with $\frac{n}{3}$ blues,  continues with $\frac{n}{3}$ whites, and ends with $\frac{n}{3}$ reds.

I think that this is the optimal algorithm, I will try to show later the correctness.

2.Is the algorithm applicable if there are 4 colors to be partitioned? 
I think it does. In the worst case, you can use counting sort, which runs at $O(nk)$ given $n$ elements and $k$ colores.